# Is the following database design good in the following table for the situation explained below

Tags: oracle, database-design

Someone has created this table with the following information:

[image]

There are more entries in the database table which I have omitted for brevity purpose.

My ultimate goal is to display the following in the User Interface:

[image]

As you can see, the `DESC` column has same value twice for `Capital,Summary etc`, same value 4 times for `First Reports`. I am planning to generate a JSON response using the webservice which would look like the following:

```
{
    "webservice_status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
    },
    "dataInfo": [{
            "desc": "Capital,Summary etc",
            "datadesc": "Counts of capital and summary ",
            "dataid": "1"

        },
        {
            "desc": "Capital,Summary etc",
            "datadesc": "Testing of capital and summary ",
            "dataid": "2"

        },
        {
            "desc": "First Reports",
            "datadesc": "Completed Successfully ",
            "dataid": "3"
        },
        {
            "desc": "First Reports",
            "datadesc": " Still Pending ",
            "dataid": "4"
        },
        {
            "desc": "First Reports",
            "datadesc": "Failed twice ",
            "dataid": "5"
        },
        {
            "desc": "First Reports",
            "datadesc": "Re attempting ... ",
            "dataid": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am wondering if I should ask the person who created this to change the database design? As far as I know, having duplicate values in the same column is a violation of some normal form?

Also, while programming, I am not sure how would I know that I need to stop at `DATAID=2` to know that my first heading will be `Capital,Summary etc` and then again, I am not sure how would I know to stop at `6` to know that my second heading is `First Reports`.

Comment: There is not enough info to answer the database design question.

Comment: You've not provided nearly enough detail, but this looks suspiciously like a case of the disastrous 'Entity-Attribute-Value' (EAV) model. Please read this: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/ and do a little googling on EAV models.  Data model (table design) should conform to Third Normal Form (google it). It should not be designed to map directly to some particular form or report.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if I should ask the person who created this to change
>   the database design? As far as I know, having duplicate values in the
>   same column is a violation of some normal form?

If the table is on the "many" side of a relationship, it can be the case that duplicates are stored in a "foreign key" column (eg see the DEPARTMENT_ID column of Oracle's sample HR.EMPLOYEES table below).  Thus, without knowing all the other details of the design - and taking them into account -, it may not be advantageous to ask for any changes to be made.

```
-- using https://livesql.oracle.com ...
select employee_id, last_name, department_id from hr.employees ;

EMPLOYEE_ID  LAST_NAME     DEPARTMENT_ID
100          King          90
101          Kochhar       90
102          De Haan       90
103          Hunold        60
104          Ernst         60
105          Austin        60
106          Pataballa     60
107          Lorentz       60
108          Greenberg    100
109          Faviet       100
110          Chen         100
...
```

> Also, while programming, I am not sure how would I know that I need to
>   stop at DATAID=2 to know that my first heading will be Capital,Summary
>   etc and then again, I am not sure how would I know to stop at 6 to
>   know that my second heading is First Reports.

In your test table, the headings are already mapped to DATADESC.  The only item changed in the example below is: the column called DESC is now: DESC_ (as the word DESC is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) - this, by the way, is something that probably *should* be changed: the name of column DESC).

```
-- table and data
create table T ( desc_ , datadesc, dataid )
as
select 'Capital,Summary etc'
, 'Counts of capital and summary', 1 from dual union
select 'Capital,Summary etc'
, 'Testing of capital and summary ', 2 from dual union
select 'First Reports'
, 'Completed Successfully', 3 from dual union
select 'First Reports'
, 'Still Pending', 4 from dual union
select 'First Reports'
, 'Failed twice ', 5 from dual union
select 'First Reports'
, 'Re attempting ...', 6 from dual ;

-- data
select * from T ;

DESC_                   DATADESC                        DATAID
Capital,Summary etc     Counts of capital and summary   1
Capital,Summary etc     Testing of capital and summary  2
First Reports           Completed Successfully          3
First Reports           Failed twice                    5
First Reports           Re attempting ...               6
First Reports           Still Pending                   4
```

You can get this resultset in JSON format, too.  Eg if you are using Oracle version 18.0 (eg @ https://livesql.oracle.com):

Query

```
select 
  json_object( 
    'desc_' is DESC_
  , 'datadesc' is DATADESC
  , 'dataid' is DATAID  
  )
from T 
order by dataid ;
```

Result

```
{
"desc_" : "Capital,Summary etc",
"datadesc" : "Counts of capital and summary",
"dataid" : 1
}
{
"desc_" : "Capital,Summary etc",
"datadesc" : "Testing of capital and summary ",
"dataid" : 2
}
{
"desc_" : "First Reports",
"datadesc" : "Completed Successfully",
"dataid" : 3
}
{
"desc_" : "First Reports",
"datadesc" : "Still Pending",
"dataid" : 4
}
{
"desc_" : "First Reports",
"datadesc" : "Failed twice ",
"dataid" : 5
}
{
"desc_" : "First Reports",
"datadesc" : "Re attempting ...",
"dataid" : 6
}
```

Another example - using sqlcl and Oracle version 12c release 12.1.0.2.0:

```
set sqlformat json

select * from T order by dataid ;

-- line breaks added for clarity
{"results":[{"columns":[{"name":"DESC_","type":"NUMBER"},{"name":"DATADESC","type":"NUMBER"},{"name":"DATAID","type":"NUMBER"}],"items":

[
 {"desc_":"Capital,Summary etc","datadesc":"Counts of capital and summary","dataid":1}
,{"desc_":"Capital,Summary etc","datadesc":"Testing of capital and summary ","dataid":2}
,{"desc_":"First Reports","datadesc":"Completed Successfully","dataid":3}
,{"desc_":"First Reports","datadesc":"Still Pending","dataid":4}
,{"desc_":"First Reports","datadesc":"Failed twice ","dataid":5}
,{"desc_":"First Reports","datadesc":"Re attempting ...","dataid":6}
]}]}
-- 6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, while programming,

I see two options. One, change the JSON to break the data on the desired formatting break.

```
{
    "webservice_status": {
        ...
    },
    "dataInfo": {
        "desc":"Capital,Summary etc",
        "items":[
            {"datadesc": "Counts of capital and summary ",
            "dataid": "1"},
            {"datadesc": "Testing of capital and summary ",
            "dataid": "2"}
        ]
     },
        {"desc": "First Reports",
        "items":[
            {"datadesc": "Completed Successfully ",
            "dataid": "3"}, ... etc.
```

(There may be a few braces missing in there. Sorry. I'm ad libing here.)

Second, in the application, iterate over the results and perform header-output processing on a change of value. In pseudo code

```
LastValue = "impossible string"

for each row
begin
    If row.desc <> LastValue
    begin
       do HeaderOuput()
       LastValue = row.desc
    end

    do LineOuput()
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of changing the JSON in the Java webservice, do you think it would be good to change it on the client side? And then use it like the following in my Javascript code.Here's the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0b8mt7qx/? Keeping JSON simple could help me in future if I have to include other things.

Comment: You have a desired output, shown in the question. If I were starting from scratch I  would format the JSON payload to make that easy, unless there was a good reason not to. If the JSON has to remain flat, as you show, then it has to be transformed to header-detail output at some point. Whether that's client side JSON post-processing (your fiddle) or not will likely be determined by your JS framework and whatever else the JSON is used for. I wouldn't get worked up either way.

Comment: "Keeping JSON simple" is laudable. Is it simpler as a flat list (that requires transforms) or when the structure of the JSON matches the meaning in the data? If you're just going to have a wider list "in the future" why bother with JSON? Why not just CSV? I don't have answers here, just asking the questions. You know your app best.